# Drawing a back-to-back plot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I would like to draw a side-by-side plot, but I don't know how to specify the common x and y-axis please see the below plot. Also, I don't know how to adjust the values (counts) at the end of the bar charts. Also, how can fix the x-axis to 300 counts?

[image]

I found an example using R (but not ggplot) from here, can anyone give me some hint on doing this using ggplot? Thanks!

Sample data:

```
df1<-structure(list(Day = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
), class = "factor"), counts = c(178L, 55L, 131L, 116L, 164L, 
96L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df2<-structure(list(Day = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"
), class = "factor"), counts = c(244L, 120L, 264L, 198L, 223L, 
163L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Code used:

rm(list = ls())

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(gridExtra)



Less <- read_dta("Data/Less.dta")
More <- read_dta("Data/More.dta")

df1 <- Less%>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
df1

df1$Day <- factor(df1$Day,levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))

g1<-ggplot(df1, aes(x = df1$Day, y = counts)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), vjust = -0.3) + 
  labs(x="Day of the week", y ="Count", fill="", title="Time")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=15))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ,family="Times", face="bold", size=15), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15),plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,0), "mm")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.key.width = unit(8, "cm"), legend.text=element_text(size=15))+
  scale_y_reverse()+coord_flip()
g1
###############

df2 <- More %>%
  group_by(Day) %>%
  summarise(counts = n())
df2

df2$Day <- factor(df2$Day,levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))

g2<-ggplot(df2, aes(x = df2$Day, y = counts)) +
  geom_bar(fill = "#0073C2FF", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts), vjust = -0.3) + 
  labs(x="Day of the week", y ="Count", fill="", title="Time")  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=15))+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = ,family="Times", face="bold", size=15), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15),axis.text.y = element_text(size=15, face="bold")) + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15)) + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15), plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,1,0), "mm")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.key.width = unit(8, "cm"), legend.text=element_text(size=15))+
   coord_flip()
g2

grid.arrange(g1, g2,
             widths=c(0.4, 0.4), ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like facets might do the job but the difficulty is getting the first x-axis in reverse and the other not. One option is to use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales()` to do the axes (disclaimer I'm the author of ggh4x).

In the example below, assume `df1` and `df2` are your sample data. I've kept the code somewhat more minimal than your example for brevity reasons.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

# Combine data.frames
all_df <- rbind(cbind(df1, facet = "Left"),
                cbind(df2, facet = "Right"))

ggplot(all_df, aes(counts, forcats::fct_rev(Day))) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = counts),
            nudge_x = 15) +
  facet_wrap(~ facet, scales = "free_x") +
  facetted_pos_scales(x = list(
    scale_x_reverse(limits = c(300, 0)),
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 300))
  ))
```

[image]